# Error occurres on leaving and refreshing page, NGRX, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I reformated my app by separating posts and comments, created two reducers for both and every time I filter comments based on postID property in comment object I get the error.

**It works first time, when I start the app, on reloading, and leaving it shows error.**

This is the selector:

```js
export const getCommentsByPostID = createSelector(getSelectedPost, getComments, (post, comments) => {
    return comments.filter(comment => comment.postID === post.id);
})
```

I'm getting undefined 'id' error. 
Here is the component code:

```js
 this.comment$ = this.store.select(fromReducer.getCommentsByPostID);
 this.post$ = this.store.select(fromReducer.getSelectedPost);
```

Comment: The problem is most likely in your reducer. Make sure that at no point the post is undefined or null.

Comment: can you post a example of your reducer? maybe is something with the reducer initial state

Comment: I agree. Common mistake I see developers make is that they select a property that is set to null/undefined.

Comment: I'm using entities, I have only 'loading' property in state, I think it could be a problem with router because, when I want to go to another page it doesn't redirect on first click, I have to click twice in order to route..`getSelectedPost` is based on router-store parameters and there is no paramter so it shows the error.

Comment: Solved it by adding `if (post === undefined) return;`